# How to get the device metadata info from google cloud iot core using listDevices

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

I would like to use listDevices to get all my devices under a registry.
[Google NodeJS Core IOT API spec](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/v1.DeviceManagerClient.html#listDevices)

I get an array back which seems to contain a metadata obj/json doc but it's empty.

```html
---
- credentials: []
  metadata: {}
  id: device001
  name: ''
  numId: '3038801391636994'
  config:
  lastConfigAckTime:
  state:
  lastConfigSendTime:
  blocked: false
  lastStateTime:
  logLevel: LOG_LEVEL_UNSPECIFIED
  gatewayConfig:
- credentials: []
  metadata: {}
  id: device002
  name: ''
  numId: '2991873732633082'
  config:
  lastConfigAckTime:
  state:
  lastConfigSendTime:
  blocked: false
  lastStateTime:
  logLevel: LOG_LEVEL_UNSPECIFIED
  gatewayConfig:
```

If I run a getDevice I do get the expected metadata but that requires a request for each device which becomes too slow and hammers resources. Bug or design?

```
const [response] = await iotClient.getDevice({name: devicePath});
```

Which actually shows the metadata

```
    Found device: device002 {
  credentials: [
    {
      expirationTime: [Object],
      publicKey: [Object],
      credential: 'publicKey'
    }
  ],
  metadata: {
    hasGPS: 'true',
    model: 'Pyton_v1',
    hasSolar: 'true',
    netType: 'WIFI'
  },
  id: 'device002'
}
```

Comment: Your data appears to be being listed in YAML and shows an array of what appears to be devices.  So you have achieved the task ... you have retrieved devices under a registry.  We seem to see that the "metadata" field is empty.  How confident are you that there is meta data associated with device001 or device002?

Comment: @Kolban I updated my question to include a printout of the getDevice(deviceid) for one of the devices listed in the getDevices(registry). It's there. But maybe its meant to be empty?? I'm trying to find devices of the model type "Python_v1". API Doc mentions metadata is not indexed and so on, But I can filter it client-side.

Answer (score 2):

I've made some tries with the device list functions and I think it is a design.

If you run the ["gcloud iot devices list" command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iot/devices/list) you get only the fields `id` and `num_id`, the  ones that are filled in your output array too.

I tried using other client libraries and I got the same results, so it looks like it is designed like this but the NodeJS library retrieves additional fields for each device.

Comment: Bummer but you are correct, I just tested this with node.js and indeed inside listDevices you have to do getDevice to get the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in the `fieldMask` parameter in listDevices api. Check the example code here:

https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices?authuser=1#getting_device_details